# Is signal analysis on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does DSP fall into our realm or Stack overflows realm?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126/does-dsp-fall-into-our-realm-or-stack-overflows-realm)

Is it fine to ask questions regarding signal analysis here? Examples:

- Should I use a Chebyshev or Butterworth filter to filter [signal]?
- Which function could have generated this pole-zero diagram?
- What kind of regulator should I use for [project]?

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126/does-dsp-fall-into-our-realm-or-stack-overflows-realm/

Comment: @endolith: Thanks, I missed that topic in my search.

Comment: Nordenfur, long and the short of it, yes, it seems to fit here. If you are very stuck in math proofs though you will probably not get a great set of feedback.